# Update table column by comparing geometry columns from other table

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have 2 tables. 1. island 2. region

[image]

[image]

I want to update island table region column based on the closet region to it using `st_distance` function. For e.g. for g1, `st_distance(g1, geom1), st_distance(g1, geom2)... st_distance(g1, geom4)` and update the region column for g1 geometry with the closet distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could work like this:

```
UPDATE island
SET region = (SELECT regions.geom <-> island.geom
              FROM regions
              ORDER BY regions.geom <-> island.geom
              LIMIT 1);
```

This can use a GiST index on `regions(geom)`, but it will still take a while if `island` is large.

Comment: The only addition is FROM regions, island

Comment: No, only `FROM regions`. The subquery refers to a column of the outer query.